# Can I add columns that are not aggreated in a pandas aggreation statement?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to generate some aggregated data to later merge with another dataset so I need specific columns.  Here is my original dataset:

```
currency    date    close
0   CAD 1992-03-02  0.8424
1   CAD 1992-03-03  0.8392
2   CAD 1995-03-15  0.7085
3   CAD 1995-03-16  0.7072
4   CAD 1995-03-17  0.7085
```

I can aggregate the date using this:

```
price_history['date'] = pd.to_datetime(price_history['date'])
price_history.groupby(price_history['date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%B'))['close'].mean()
```

But I get this:

```
date
1989-December    0.861562
1989-November    0.855259
1989-October     0.852055
1990-April       0.859286
1990-August      0.873570
                   ...   
2021-February    1.087577
2021-January     1.075098
2021-June        1.104932
2021-March       1.090641
2021-May         1.116390
```

What I would like is: currency(from the original dataframe), date, close.

Date & close are from the aggregated dataframe.

I think the two problems are:

1. I am not sure how to add currency to the dataset
2. the mean of the monthly closing prices column is not labelled so I'm not sure how I'll be able to select it later to join with another dataset.

What can I do to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To bring currency into the dataset, you can include `currency` column as one of the group variables, which makes sense since it's not meaningful to calculate mean for different currencies; The result column is not labelled because it's *pandas Series* object, it has a name just not displayed. You can use `reset_index` to convert it back to a dataframe:

```
price_history.groupby([
  price_history.currency, 
  price_history['date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%B')]
)['close'].mean().reset_index()

#  currency        date     close
#0      CAD  1992-March  0.840800
#1      CAD  1995-March  0.708067
```

Comment: Thank you, related question, say I want more than currency but instead all values in the dataframe. How could I modified about to get it?

Comment: If you meant you have more columns (non group variables) other than currency you need to keep, you can use transform('mean') which keeps the size of data, and then assign it back to original data frame:  `price_history['close_mean'] = price_history.groupby(price_history['date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%B'))['close'].transform('mean')`

Answer (score 0):

You can try `price_history.concat(currency_to_concat, ignore_index=True)`.